# Chartjs render only the last in loop (ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

Im using [Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) to draw charts in my ionic app. Everything works fine excepts the it renders the last in loop. Lets say there's there objects [0,1,2], it renders only 2, well using `ng-repeat`, it repeat 3 times since theres 3 objects in the array. ill attach my view and consoles log.

**Console**:

[image: There are 3 pie objects, it only renders the last in loop]

**App view**:

[image: As you can see theres are the same charts]

**script:**

```
for(i in blogs.data) {
   if(blogs.data[i].post_type_id == 3) {

        var chartdraw = JSON.parse(blogs.data[i].chart.data);

        if(blogs.data[i].chart.chart_type_id == 1){
            $scope.pieData = chartdraw;
            $log.info('pieData:',$scope.pieData);
        }
        else if(blogs.data[i].chart.chart_type_id == 2){
            $scope.barData = chartdraw;
            $log.info('barData:',$scope.barData);
        }
        else if(blogs.data[i].chart.chart_type_id == 3){
            $scope.lineData = chartdraw;
            $log.info('lineData:',$scope.lineData);
        }
        else if(blogs.data[i].chart.chart_type_id == 4){
            $scope.numberData = chartdraw;
            $log.info('numberData:',$scope.numberData);
        }

   }
}
```

**view:**

```
      <div class="card image" ng-if="blog.post_type_id == 3" >
         <a href="#/app/home/{{blog.id}}">
          <div class="thumb">
            <div>
              <canvas piechart options="chartOptions" data="pieData" width="150" height="150" ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 1">
              </canvas>
              <canvas barchart options="chartOptions" data="barData" width="150" height="150" ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 2">
              </canvas>
              <canvas linechart options="chartOptions" data="lineData" width="150" height="150" ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 3">
              </canvas>
              <div ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 4">
                <p ng-bind-html="numberData.details[0].value"></p>
                <p ng-bind-html="numberData.details[0].label"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center cat-icon">
              <span class="icon-wrapper">
                <i class="icon ion-stats-bars" style="position:relative;"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h4 class="title">{{blog.title}}</h4>
          <p class="details"><i class="icon ion-calendar"></i> {{blog.created_at}}</p>
         </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is this - charts from each of your blog posts (all of the ones in the picture happen to be pie) are bound to one of 3 objects depending on the chart type (for the picture, its $scope.pieData for all the charts)

The rest is a result of how angular works - it doesn't matter what the value of $scope.pieData *was* - when you update $scope.pieData, angular updates all references to $scope.pieData (and consequently the charts get updated as well).

In your case, you keep updating it in the loop and so at the end of the loop $scope.pieData is whatever was in the last post, consequently all your charts have that data. You need to have one scope variable for **each** chart

Here is a code pen illustrating what is happening in your case - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doOqjN (I just removed chartjs to make it clearer) - notice that all the values are 3000.

And here is the codepen with the fix - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbqBM. Notice that the values are now all different. The only lines I changed are

```
<div ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 1">{{blog.chart.data}}</div>
<div ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 2">{{blog.chart.data}}</div>
<div ng-if="blog.chart.chart_type_id == 3">{{blog.chart.data}}</div>
```

And you actually don't need the entirety of your script block!

You could probably optimize a bit more and I didn't actually do anything about numberData.details because I wasn't sure what it was supposed to be for.

Comment: Thanks man for the concept and codepen. I need to actually get the index for each objects from the api hence the loop. `i` would be undefined if i take it out of the loop. the api structure is like this, Objects [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> there are 4 types of posts, so i have to sort first using `post.id.post_type_id` , then if the post is for charts, I have to sort it again as there are 4 different types of charts , `post.id.post_type_id.chart.chart_type_id` . My script is just not working or it is badly structured.

Comment: Can't quite visualize it, but you might want to set up a parallel structure in the scope (i.e. one scope object for each chart's data).